# Display progress indicator in another thread using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I was wondering if that's possible to create an animated progress indicator that won't be frozen while there's an ongoing operation in the main thread. I thought that maybe creating second thread and using it to display a simple dialog (`wxGenericProgressDialog` in this case) would solve the problem. I've tried multiple approaches of doing that, but all of them failed. There's a simple example:

```
class ThreadTester : public wxThread {
public:
    ThreadTester(wxMutex *mutex, wxCondition *condition)
    {
        m_mutex = mutex;
        m_condition = condition;
    }

    virtual wxThread::ExitCode Entry() override {

        // This is usually non-blocking operation - this window
        // is by default non-modal
        d = new wxGenericProgressDialog("test1", "test2", 100, 0);

        wxMutexLocker lock(*m_mutex);
        m_condition->Broadcast();

        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    wxCondition *m_condition;
    wxMutex *m_mutex;

    wxGenericProgressDialog *d;
};

void MyFrame::PerformSomeTimeConsumingOperation(wxCommandEvent& event)
{

    wxMutex mutex;
    wxCondition condition(mutex);

    mutex.Lock();

    auto t = new ThreadTester(&mutex, &condition);
    t->Run();

    // Wait until showing dialog is completed
    condition.Wait();

    // Perform some time-consuming operation here

    // Kill thread (and hide the dialog) after the operation is completed
    t->Kill();

}
```

When I remove that line

```
d = new wxGenericProgressDialog("test1", "test2", 100, 0);
```

it will work just fine. That's why I started to think that creating any dialog with wxWidgets (even parent-less) requires some kind of attention of the main thread. And that's why it's not possible to create a dialog in any other thread when the main thread is blocked. Is that correct? Has anyone achieved what I want to do? I know that the recommended way of doing that would be to move time-consuming operation to another thread and to put gui-handling in the main thread, but since that would require redesigning some parts of my application, I decided to give it a try this way first.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch you approach - perform a long running task on a secondary thread and do GUI updates/refresh in the main.

The way you think about the problem is wrong - threads are explicitly exists to solve just this problem - perform a long running task while the main thread is running.

Moreover - you approach will not guarantee to work on any of the 3 major platforms supported by wxWidgets.

Bottom line - do a task in a thread and send a notification event to update the main one - GUI.